# Why is this not handling my Exception correctly?

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am trying to process payments and need to notify customers if the payment succeeded or failed. If it fails, I need to notify the customer and also be notified myself of the error and have flask setup to email me all errors. I've come up with this:

```
@app.route('/charge/',methods=['POST']) 
def charge():
    try:
      # charge payment using Stripe checkout
      ...
      ...
      # done processing      
      flash('Thanks!')
      return jsonify()
    except:
      flash("Error")
      raise
```

Upon receiving a response via AJAX, Stripe checkout will reload the page so that my flash messages are displayed. When the transaction succeeds the page reloads and I get the "Thanks!" flash message but when it doesn't succeed the page still reloads but I don't get the "Error" flash message.

Why?

EDIT:
If I change the except to:

```
except:
      flash("Error")
      print "THIS IS PRINTING"
      raise
```

"THIS IS PRINTING" gets printed in my console right before the exception is thrown. The flash message still doesn't show on the page reload.

Comment: Are you sure a failed transaction raises an exception? Try putting anything in the except block...is it executing at all?

Comment: yes, it does. The exception gets raised on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you are mentioning the flash message that happens after the exception is not sent back to the template because you are not reloading the page in any way. As mentioned in the previous comment, the raise method simply re-raises the exception, without handling it. The reason that you can see the printing statement but not the flash message is exactly this: the print gets executed on the console, but the flash message, even if it is executed, is not forwarded to any template.

A correct way of doing it would be:

```
@app.route('/charge/',methods=['POST']) 
def charge():
    try:
      # charge payment using Stripe checkout
      ...
      ...
      # done processing      
      flash('Thanks!')
      return jsonify()
    except:
      flash("Error")
      return redirect('/charge/')
```

Also, the use of jsonify() is not correct. It should be like: `jsonify(*data to be converted, in dictionary form preferably*)`.

In order to alert yourself through email, you need to first have installed, configured  and initialized correctly an email library. I am assuming that you are using/might use [Flask-mail](http://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/). The code might be as follows:

```
    @app.route('/charge/',methods=['POST']) 
    def charge():
        try:
          # charge payment using Stripe checkout
          ...
          ...
          # done processing      
          flash('Thanks!')
          return jsonify()
        except Exception as err:
          flash("Error")
          msg = Message("Hi there, you have this error:"+err+" on page '/charge/'. Jolly good!",sender="mailer@example.com", recipients=["yourself@example.com"])
          return redirect('/charge/')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `except` block do not re-`raise` the exception; this will simply not return anything to the client. Can you re-direct or reload the page? In any case you will have to return something, not raise.

Comment: there's no way to alert both the user and myself if something goes wrong?